# Should chrome extension commands (hotkey) names be changed when updating to Manifest Version 3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, browser-action

Recently, Google has introduced Chrome Extensions Manifest Version 3. One major change was the consolidation of the `Browser Action` and `Page Action` popups into one single "Action" popup. This change is reflected throughout most of the APIs.

One feature of Chrome Extensions is to allow the user to press hotkeys from throughout the browser to trigger an event in the extension. These hotkeys are registered in the Extension `manifest.json` file. In the past, each command would be named with either a custom name you would listen for in the code, `_execute_browser_action` to use this command to open the browser action popup, or `_execute_page_action` to use this command to open the page action popup.

I would expect that the two old popup command names would be replaced by one: `_execute_action`. However, the [specifications](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/), which have been updated for manifest version 3, still shows two command names. Could you please tell me what I should do?

Comment: _execute_action works for me. Give it a chance ;-)

Comment: @Robbi Thanks! If you want, you can make it an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Do not mention it